Can what makes sounds rhyme with each other be characterized in terms their wave properties?
So, I don't really know what I'm talking about here, but here it goes.
With fourier analysis I bet you can take apart a sound wave, and the various properties (pitch, tone) of the sound traveling through the air can probably be determined via the properties of the constituent sound wave parts (wavelength, frequency, amplitude, phase shifts).
The word "Tree" rhymes with the word "Free" and "Key." Can what makes words/sounds rhyme with each other be characterized via their corresponding wave properties??

Are you asking only if it can be done, or more technically also how it can be done? This can greatly change the scope/depth of the answers you may get here. Either way, I'm not sure if "soft-question" is an appropriate tag here because it definitely involves actual physics.

That "ree" sound at the end of each of those words cannot be described as a simple waveform.* It continuously evolves from the waveform of the "r" sound to the waveform of the "ee" sound over a span of time. People who study human speech usually prefer not to analyze those sounds in the time domain (i.e., not as waveforms) but in the frequency domain instead (i.e., as spectra). They often use spectrograms (also sometimes called "waterfall plots") to visualize how the spectrum of a sound like "ree" changes over time.
Google for "speech spectrogram" and click the "images" tab to see examples.

* Technically, the "ree" sound can be described as a waveform, but the period of the wave would be the same as the length of time it takes for you to make the whole sound. The frequency of the wave would be something like the number of times per second you repeat yourself saying "reereereereeree..."
I prefer not to call that a simple waveform.
